# GNOME has grey bar on top and bottom after upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10, how do I fix it to how it's supposed to look?

Tags: 17.10, panel, gnome-shell

This is how my desktop looks after the update, the top bar turning grey and the addition of the bottom bar happened after the update.

[image]

From my searching of screenshots this does not appear to be how it is supposed to be. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What screenshots did you see?

Comment: You forgot to show us what it looked like before, i.e. what you expected instead. If this is normal behaviour then we have no basis for comparison. => poor question

Comment: @NonnyMoose Most probably OP means screenshots from articles on Artful. But yes, I agree, OP should've been clearer with the description.

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, I meant a default fresh install that was luckily understood. Seems I had indeed defaulted to Gnome classic, possibly in absence of the wayland logins because I was using nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems you have somehow logged into a GNOME classic session.

Reboot and after entering your password click on the cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button.

It should show you different available sessions. Try "Ubuntu" (or Ubuntu on Xorg) or "GNOME" (or GNOME on Xorg, but not GNOME Classic or GNOME Flashback or anything else) session.

Comment: I cannot find Gnome (on wayland), I only get gnome on Xorg or Ubuntu on Xorg. How can I login with wayland?

Comment: First, thanks pomsky. And I had the same issue, probably due to installing nvidia drivers. After switching back to nouveau (possibly wrong spelling) wayland was available for me. I guess it might have defaulted to gnome classic because wayland was absent?