# Ubuntu Gnome - How to remove Gnome and install regular Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10

I installed Ubuntu (16.04) on my machine, but I also wanted to check out other display managers so I ended up using Gnome.

I just upgraded to 17.10 which ships with Gnome, but I believe something got messed up with the preexisting configuration and the new Ubuntu, I get two panels on the top and bottom parts of the screen and no left side panel as it looks like in the demos.

Is there a way to completely remove the Gnome version I had in my system with all of it's configuration and install the one that ships with Ubuntu? (ideally without having to reinstall the whole operating system)

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed. In my case the options on the cog icon during login were `Gnome on Xorg` and `Ubuntu on Xorg`. `Ubuntu on Xorg` was the one that worked. Does that mean I have more than one instances of GNOME installed? And if so, how I uninstall only the extra one?

Comment: That means your hardware doesn't support Wayland. Nvidia?

Comment: @pomsky :( Nvidia. Is there something I should try?

Comment: See if this comment helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966468/gnome-has-grey-bar-on-top-and-bottom-after-upgrade-from-17-04-to-17-10-how-do-i#comment1547592_966470

Comment: If you want to remove the "GNOME" session in the cog list, I think you can just remove the `gnome-session` package.