# No wayland preinstalled on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, wayland

I just installed ubuntu 17.10, and soon I discovered I have no Wayland! In GDM there are no additional sessions, X11 is being used:

[image]

Comment: nvidia? then see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/967009/no-option-to-switch-from-xorg-to-wayland-on-ubuntu-17-10-login

Comment: Please provide some hardware details.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue by changing from the proprietary NVIDA driver to Ubuntu default.

Settings > Details will provide a snapshot.

details proprietary driver
[image]

details default driver
[image]

Also, check posts on issues with NVIDA and Wayland.