# Does Ubuntu 20.04/10 support Wayland with Nvidia proprietary driver?

Tags: nvidia, wayland, 20.10

I installed Pop OS 20.04 nVidia version (based on Ubuntu 20.04), and Wayland did not seem to work because I could not set different scalings on different monitors (like 100% for monitor1, and 200% for monitor2).

Next, I installed Ubuntu 20.10 and installed the latest proprietary nVidia driver. I still could not set different scaling. At the login screen, I did not see the small menu to choose between X11 and Wayland, so I searched Google and installed things related to Wayland and set the `EnableWayland=true` in the config file. Now I see the small menu to choose the session type at the login screen, but the selected was Ubuntu, and the other item was "Gnome on Xorg". Isn't that X11?

I rebooted the PC to make it sure, and I chose the "Ubuntu" session. Yet, when I checked the session type, it was "X11". Did I do something wrong, or is this because Wayland is not supported with the proprietary nVidia driver, due to the frame buffer or memory support issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No option to switch from xorg to Wayland on Ubuntu 17.10 login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967009/no-option-to-switch-from-xorg-to-wayland-on-ubuntu-17-10-login)