# How do I disable a bottom panel with the list of open windows on GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome-shell, panel, taskbar

How do I disable "Workspace dock" (a bottom panel with the list of open windows and a workspace indicator-cum-switcher), the one that is over "Plank" in the screenshot below?

[image: screen]

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you're calling "Workspace dock" seems to be the list of open windows triggered by the [Window List](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/) extension.

You can disable it from the "*Extensions*" section of *(GNOME) Tweaks* or this webpage: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/.

Also if your desktop looks like the following image, you have [logged into a "GNOME Classic" session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966468/gnome-has-grey-bar-on-top-and-bottom-after-upgrade-from-17-04-to-17-10-how-do-i).

[image]