# 18.04 what is this weird bottom bar?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, taskbar

I don't know how I got this and I don't know how to get rid of it. Is it some extension?

It is redundant since I have a bar on the left. Please help me get rid of it.
[image: You may need to zoom to see it]

Comment: I think you installed a plugin for gnome that let's you see currently luanched apps, sort of like a task bar.

Comment: See: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/

Comment: Which flavour (Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie ... Xubuntu) of Ubuntu are you running? How did you install it? Or did you upgrade it (in that case how and from which flavour of Ubuntu)? Did you install some other desktop environment after the main installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable "Window list"? Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979072/how-to-disable-window-list-ubuntu-17-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was default ubuntu. And it was the extension listed below. No idea how I got it. But removing it works.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. You can 'accept' your own answer. This will tell other people with the same question that there is a useful answer.

Comment: @sudodus Yeah I wasn't able to do that. Said something about 2 days. Then I forgot. Bad system.