# Why do I have two docks in Ubuntu, and how do I get rid of one?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-dock, dock

As you can see here:

[image]

I have the thin gray dock in the bottom as well as the standard one on the right. How do I get rid of the one in the bottom? I was reading up on how to get an OSX like dock and I was trying to install gnome-dock (which might be the one already installed lol) and suddenly I noticed that the little gray one on the bottom had appeared.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and expand on the "trying to install gnome-dock" part. What *exact* changes did you make? Also see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979072/how-do-i-disable-a-bottom-panel-with-the-list-of-open-windows-on-gnome-3