# Lost Icons and top and bottom bar after restart

Tags: gnome

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and after playing around with it last night I got where I wanted it for now. I come back today and the top bar is white there is now a dock at the bottom that wasn't there last night. Icons for apps like the terminal icon is just a piece of paper.

white top bar:
[image: white top bar]

missing icons:
[missing icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGocI.png) (slightly NSFW)

I tried signing out and going to the cogwheel to change the shell but there is no cogwheel to even change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNOME has grey bar on top and bottom after upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10, how do I fix it to how it's supposed to look?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966468/gnome-has-grey-bar-on-top-and-bottom-after-upgrade-from-17-04-to-17-10-how-do-i) Do you get the cogwheel after a reboot?

Comment: I have no cogwheel after rebooting.

Comment: Strange issue! This is 17.10, right? Try reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package by running `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Tried that came up with "ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.404.1)." and yes 17.10